# Obtained source code of python function is wrong

Tags: python, inspect, dill

I would like to obtain the source code of a Python function. However, the functions I am dealing with have decorators that are instantiated with functions themselves. It seems like `inspect` or `dill` have problems with that. In particular, I tried the following MWE:

```
class Decorator(object):
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item
        self.func = None
    def __call__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        return self

@Decorator(42)
def fun_1():
    pass

@Decorator(lambda x: 42)
def fun_2():
    pass

@Decorator(fun_2.item)
def fun_3():
    pass

import inspect
print("Inspect results")
print(inspect.getsource(fun_1.func))
print(inspect.getsource(fun_2.func))
print(inspect.getsource(fun_3.func))

import dill
print("Dill results")
print(dill.source.getsource(fun_1.func))
print(dill.source.getsource(fun_2.func))
print(dill.source.getsource(fun_3.func))
```

For functions `fun_1` and `fun_3`, this gives the expected results. For `fun_2` (although it is essentially the same as fun_3), the source code as returned by `inspect` or `dill` is just wrong - it only gives me the decorator line. I would expect to get

```
@Decorator(lambda x: 42)
def fun_2():
    pass
```

but all I get is

```
@Decorator(lambda x: 42)
```

I can imagine that both modules just search for the first function declaration. Is this assumption correct and is there a good workaround besides reimplementing `inspect` or `dill`?

*Edit:* I am using Python 2.7, but experienced the same behavior using Python 3.4.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the `dill` author.  I think you've found a bug in `inspect`, with regard to parsing code blocks containing a `lambda` as an argument in a decorator.

```
>>> f = lambda x: 42
>>> @Decorator(f)
... def fun_4():
...     pass
... 
>>> 
>>> print dill.source.getsource(fun_4.func)
@Decorator(f)
def fun_4():
    pass

>>>
```

Note that the above works, when you simply use a pointer to the `lambda` object.  So that's your workaround.

I believe this corner case is a bug in `inspect`, which `dill` is using under the covers... so it's a bug in `dill` also.

I've opened a ticket on the `dill` GitHub page, and I'll investigate it further to see (1) if there's an easy workaround that can be implemented in `dill`, and (2) if indeed it's a bug in `inspect` (I'm guessing it is) -- and if so, it should be populated up to the python developers.  Here's the link to the ticket: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/221